Performance Issues on Android WebView with React and Capacitor v6: Excessive Idle Time During User Interactions
I'm currently building a vocabulary trainer app using React and Capacitor v6. While the app performs exceptionally well on the web and has good performance on iOS, I'm facing significant performance issues on Android. These issues are present across different devices and Android versions, including a physical device and an AVD emulator running Android 14 (API Level 34).
App Overview:
The app displays a word to the user, and upon clicking the "solve" button, it:

Fetches the translation(s) of the word from an API.
Updates multiple user statistics based on their interaction.

Performance Analysis:
I conducted a performance analysis using Chrome DevTools by connecting my AVD device (emulator). The analysis captures a single user interaction.
Here is the result from the performance profiling:

As highlighted in the screenshot, there is a considerable amount of idle time during the interaction, which is causing noticeable delays in the app’s responsiveness.
Further, the Android-Studio Profiler shows that I have a maximum of 22% CPU consumption and a maximum of 95MB memory consumption.

I already tried to offloaded as much processing as possible to the API.
I already made sure to enable hardware acceleration on my android
app.
I tried to improve performance by doing even more code splitting.

Additional Notes:

I am using the fetch API to do my requests and TanStack-Query for asynchronous state management.
The requests use HTTP/2 and the connection to make requests is shared for multiple requests instead of opening a new connection for every request.
There are 4 preflight calls before the requests, but they only need 15-25ms.
I don't use any animations in this use case.
The performance of my app is very good when I open it in my Chrome-App (or any other browser app) on my device.

Questions:

What could be causing this excessive idle time on Android, and how can I diagnose it further?
What additional steps can I take to optimize the app’s performance specifically for Android devices?

Unfortunately, I cannot provide a link to my app because it is not realeased, yet. I am testing it on my staging environment and the app is only in the internal testing state in the app stores. However, feel free to ask if you need further information.
I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

I was able to significantly improve the performance of my app, reducing the time from 1660ms to just 410ms.

The issue I was encountering involved using the capacitor-secure-storage-plugin to store OAuth JWTs. Initially, every time I made an HTTP request to my API, I retrieved the access token from secure storage, which turned out to be quite performance-intensive.
To resolve this, I implemented a hybrid approach. I still use secure storage to persist the tokens, ensuring they are stored securely. However, after retrieving a token for the first time, I store it in memory for subsequent accesses. This drastically reduces the need to repeatedly access secure storage, improving performance.
Here's the implementation of my custom CapacitorSecureStorage:
import { KeyValueStorageInterface } from '@aws-amplify/core';
import { SecureStoragePlugin } from 'capacitor-secure-storage-plugin';

export default class CapacitorSecureStorage
    implements KeyValueStorageInterface
{
    storageObject: Record<string, string | null> = {};
    private static instance: CapacitorSecureStorage;

    private constructor() {}

    public static getInstance(): CapacitorSecureStorage {
        if (!CapacitorSecureStorage.instance) {
            CapacitorSecureStorage.instance = new CapacitorSecureStorage();
        }

        return CapacitorSecureStorage.instance;
    }

    async setItem(key: string, value: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await SecureStoragePlugin.set({ key, value });
            this.storageObject[key] = value;
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }

    async getItem(key: string): Promise<string | null> {
        try {
            if (key in this.storageObject) {
                return this.storageObject[key];
            }

            const result = await SecureStoragePlugin.get({ key });
            this.storageObject[key] = result.value || null;

            return result.value || null;
        } catch (error) {
            this.storageObject[key] = null;
            return null;
        }
    }

    async removeItem(key: string): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await SecureStoragePlugin.remove({ key });
            delete this.storageObject[key];
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }

    async clear(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await SecureStoragePlugin.clear();
            this.storageObject = {};
        } catch (error) {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    }
}

By using this approach, I’ve managed to significantly reduce the time taken for HTTP requests, as tokens are now quickly accessed from memory after the first retrieval from secure storage.
